# Function adds "blank" 'option' into 'select' aside from the wanted 'option'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, foreach, drop-down-menu

I have an big array of objects. I took all of the unique studentNames and put them into another array.

```
const unique = [...new Set(allStudentData.map(item => item.studentName))]; 
console.log(unique)
```

[And the console log gives me the correct output for that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOBde.png)

The problem is as follows. I have created a 'select' and I want to push these names into the 'select' as 'options'.

It gives me the unique names as 'option'. But it also gives me a "blank" option after each name that seems to have the value of all names.

[Here u can see the good 'option' and the "blank" ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfNdK.png)

[This is what happens when I click on "Evelyn", other names work as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvGXM.png)

[This is what happens when I click on a "blank", it sees it like all of the names.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euU3q.png)

Heres the code for adding the 'options'

```
const sss=
    <select id='sel' value={picked} onChange={x=>setPicked(x.target.value)}>
                <option disabled selected>Select a student</option>
    </select>

function Addsss(){
  useEffect(()=>
    unique.forEach(x=>{
       document.getElementById('sel').innerHTML += '<option value="' + x + '">' + x + "<option/>"    
    }));
  }
```

I was expecting the output to be like in the 2nd picture but without the "blanks".
And I havent mentioned it yet  but I am using React.js,

Comment: Never modify dom directly in react

Comment: try pass an array as second argument to `useEffect`, like `useEffect(() => unique( ... ), [])`.

Comment: you should use `map` method on the unique array in jsx instead of using `innerHTML`.